# What are the limits of small 3D printed gears?

Tags: materials, gears, stresses, 3d-printing, power-transmission

How much tangential force should I expect a 10~20mm pitch diameter/1.5mm gear module 3D printed rack and pinion system to support without breaking nor sliding?

Comment: Depends on material, layer height and infill%. Anyway your gears have barely enough teeth at 20 mm dia not to need undercuts or excessive shift and that will severely limit your tooth strength. Consider using a module of 1.

Comment: If we are talking about a 1 mm module PLA/ABS spur gears what is definitely too much in your experience? 10N?

Comment: If we are talking 3D printed gears, why not just print some and test them?

Comment: @joojaa is right, you will need finer pitch gears for that size based on the geometry of the tooth. Bending strength also depends on tooth thickness. A practical design consideration is tooth thickness to be no more than half the pitch diameter. So for 10 mm thick, 20 tooth, mod 1 PLA/ABS pinion with a rack I'd say 10N is close to your bending limit